# When I push view controller its take time to navigate

Tags: ios, swift3, swift3.2

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AbcViewController") as! AbcViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: ViewDidLoad() method contains heavy task?

Comment: Did you try in main queue ?

Comment: yes @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: In your `AbcViewController` what you are doing in viewDidLoad 
?

Comment: Add code of AbcViewController

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AbcViewController") as! AbcViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        } @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: no more code in abc AbcViewController @jigneshVadadoriya

Comment: @AvadhBambhroliya great ,from where you are calling this push code

Comment: its take only when i run my ipad. when i run my app in simulator its work properly @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: at button click event @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: where you run that code  ??????

Comment: @AvadhBambhroliya Try in other devices too. you might facing device issue here.

Comment: ok thanks @PrashantTukadiya do you think its memory issue?

Comment: @AvadhBambhroliya It is very difficult to say but yes it might be. first try to push other view controller and check is that same behaviour you are getting

Comment: ok let's try @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya all controller take time when i push

Comment: do we have other option? @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya do we have other option?

Comment: at button click event @Sh_Khan

Comment: the main thread may be busy doing a non ui process  check your code

Comment: @Sh_Khan but its run properly in simulator

Comment: simulator uses all Mac  capabilities not same to limited device ones

Comment: now what should i do? @Sh_Khan

Comment: you better share some code or send me a demo of the problem link in github

Comment: @Sh_Khan no more code in ViewDidLoad() i try with its blank but still same issue

Comment: share a demo............

Comment: Okay i will send @Sh_Khan

Comment: @Sh_Khan no issue found at new demo do you think that issue is setup design?

Answer (score 0):

I will happy to help you

> Please try this code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)   
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AbcViewController") as! AbcViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
})
```

**Thank You

Yash Shekhada**